# Close Sharepoint modal popup code behind

Tags: sharepoint, popup, modal-dialog

I am using sp2010 visual web part, on click on one visual webpart,opening another visual web part as a modalpupup,on button click pupup i am doing for server side operation, after this want to close popup from button click after performing server side operation and also want to refresh parent page.

In attached image on click of approve/reject opening modalpopup,and on click of submit button want to close this popup,

Need help

Answer (score 0):

After success of onclick function modal will be closed . Or clicking on close button which is added in html modal will be closed

function btnApprove_OnClientClick() {

```
    //ur code for server side


    SPContext.executeQueryAsync(btnApprove_Success, btnApprove_Fail);
}

function btnApprove_Success() {
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose();


}

 function btnApprove_Fail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


<input id="Close" type="submit" value="Close" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(); return false;" /></td>
```